# How to display grids in separate cells?

Tags: notebooks, output-formatting

```
Format[primeFactorForm[n_Integer]] := 
  Times @@ Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[n] /. _[x_] :> x

block[n_Integer] :=
  Join @@@ Array[{#, primeFactorForm@#} &[# + 16*#2] &, {16, 4}, {64 n - 63, 0}]

grid[m_?MatrixQ] := 
  With[{th = AbsoluteThickness[3]}, Grid[m, Dividers -> ({#, #} &@{th, {True}, th})]]

Array[grid @ block @ # &, 4] // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Uh, what does "how to do it" mean? Please elaborate. Also, your code doesn't run, it just gives errors. Please fix it.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP wants each grid in individual cells.

Comment: I edited content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to place each grid into a separate cell, change the last line to this:

```
Scan[Print, Array[grid @ block @ # &, 4]]
```

or this:

```
Print ~Scan~ Array[grid@block@# &, 4]
```

or this:

```
Array[grid@block@# &, 4] // Scan[Print, #]&
```

... as suits your taste.

*Mathematica* version 10 allows this nice-looking alternative form:

```
Array[grid @ block @ # &, 4] // Scan[Print]
```

Comment: If my answer reflects what you are trying to do, please change the title of your question to something more meaningful.  For example: _How to display grids in separate cells?_